# cannot access to external usb HDD

Tags: mount

I have an external hard drive but cannot access the information on it. I tried to access via Ubuntu and Windows, but both show the same message: device "0 megabytes".

I tried to mount the device but it shows this message:

```
mount:only root user can mount /dev/sdb on /mnt/usb-JMicron_USB_to_ATA_ATAPI_Bridge_152D203380B6-0:0
```

Comment: have you tried mounting with `sudo` in front of your mount command?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sudo to execute the mount command.  Sudo will execute the command with root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you need to be **root**, you don't want to mount the whole disk using `mount /dev/sdb`!

Instead, you will most likely want to mount a **partition** on that disk, using

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/whatever
```